# Database values with PHP function

Tags: php

I want to call a php function, returns database values.

```
public function readdata() { 
    $id = "";
    $name = "";
    $sth = $db->execute('SELECT * FROM mynumbers m WHERE m.id>1 ORDER BY m.id ASC');
    foreach ($sth as $s) {
       $id .= $s->id;
       $name .= $s->name;       
    }
    return compact('id', 'name');        
}

$rd = readdata();
$get_id = $rd['id'];
$get_name = $rd['name'];    
echo $get_id;
echo $get_id.$get_name.'<br>';
```

When I execute the code, it shows the output as:

```
7891011
7891011Text1Text2Text3Text4Text5
```

But I want as a single value vertically displayed. Do I need to explode ' | '

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can easily change your existing code slightly and get what you expected,

```
<?php
    public function readdata() { 
    $id = "";
    $name = "";
    $sth = $db->execute('SELECT * FROM mynumbers m WHERE m.id>1 ORDER BY m.id ASC');
    foreach ($sth as $s) {
       $array[$s->id] = $s->name;  # building id => name structure   
    }
    return $array;     
}

$rd = readdata();
# now readdata() will return data as below array
$array = [7=>'text1',8=>'text2',9=>'text3',10=>'text4',11=>'text5'];
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
   $result[] = $k." ".$v;
}
echo implode("\n", $result);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/PusI4

Comment: These are dynamic values from database. The code written is for static values.

Comment: @Corren it should work for dynamic values also from the database. Did you check my code properly, I put the static `$array` as an example for you to understand the structure

Comment: I want to display id and name as different values and echo them.